# Preferred style for passing props to components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm getting back into React and want to stick close to best practices.  With that said, I couldn't find any documentation for the best way to pass functions into a child component.  More specifically, If the function I'm passing to the child component needs to use props from the parent component as arguments, which of the following is more in line with best practices.

```
<Button
  increaseCount={() => props.increaseCount(props.title)}
  label="loadMore"
/>

const Button = props => {
  return <button onClick={props.increaseCount}>{props.label}</button>;
};
```

or

```
<Button
  title={props.title}
  increaseCount={props.increaseCount}
  label="loadMore"
/>

const Button = props => {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => props.increaseCount(props.title)}>
      {props.label}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Both will work, but since this is a small application, I may not see any performance impacts or maintainability issues that could arise as the app grows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your `Button` logic, the *"Rule of thumb"* is passing the minimum properties which are necessary:

```
// JSX
<Button
  increaseCount={() => props.increaseCount(props.title)}
  label="loadMore"
/>

// `title` is not used within the component
const Button = props => {
  return <button onClick={props.increaseCount}>{props.label}</button>;
};
```

On the other hand, misuse of unnecessary properties opens opportunities for bugs.

Also, there is a use case when you may break your existing component logic.

For example, when your app grows, you may want to change `increaseCount` logic to accept two parameters and not one, you then will need to remember visiting the `Button` implementation and change it accordingly:

```
// You may misuse the `props.title` 
// and component may break on changing `increaseCount` logic
<Button
  title={props.title}
  increaseCount={props.increaseCount}
  label="loadMore"
/>

//              v props.title not used within the component
const Button = props => {
  return (
//                                              v Notice the bug, `props.label`
//                          v What happens when increaseCount logic changes?
    <button onClick={() => props.increaseCount(props.label)}>
      {props.label}
    </button>
  );
};
```